# DIV on DIV switching on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 different difficulties for this game I am making. The code I have right now only allows me to click "medium" and "hard". This only changes the elements inside the DIV. I can't seem to make the "easy" button work or even the other ones to work right. Right now it's not replacing the whole DIV with the other but it just displays the content of the other one inside the current one. I think it might be caused by the ".innerHTML" part and I'm not sure what to switch it out with for it all to work.

```
<script>
  function show(param_div_id) {
    document.getElementById('divbox3').innerHTML = document.getElementById(param_div_id).innerHTML;
  }

</script>

<!-- Border for the game --> 
   <form id = "divbox3" name = "quiz" > 
      <div class="game-button" style="width:50%"> 
         <button onclick="show('divbox3')">Easy</button>
         <button onclick="show('divbox3med')">Medium</button>
         <button onclick="show('divbox3hard')">Hard</button>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>

<!-- Easy Quiz code -->
      <p class = "questions">Most moles have an extra thumb to dig with. <b> True or False? </b></p>
   <input id = "textbox" type = "text" name = "q1">

      <p class = "questions">What is the smallest country in the world? <b> Tuvalu - Vatican City - Monaco </b></p>
   <input id = "textbox" type = "text" name = "q2">

      <p class = "questions">What is the biggest atom on the periodic table? <b> Uranium - Francium - Radium - Lead </b></p>
   <input id = "textbox" type = "text" name = "q3">

      <p class = "questions">Who is the richest man in the world? <b> Bill Gates - Jeff Bezos - Elon Musk </b></p>
   <input id = "textbox" type = "text" name = "q4">

   <input id = "buttoneasy" type = "button" value = "Finished!" onclick = "check();">
</form>

   <div id = "easyscoresheet">
      <p id = "easynumber_correct"></p>
      <p id = "easymessage"></p>
   </div>

   <!-- Border for the game --> 
   <form id = "divbox3med" name = "quizmed" style="display:none;"> 
         <div class="game-button" style="width:50%"> 
         <button onclick="show('divbox3')">Easy</button>
         <button onclick="show('divbox3med')">Medium</button>
         <button onclick="show('divbox3hard')">Hard</button>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>

<!-- Medium Quiz code -->
  <p class = "questions">What type of animal is Bambi? <b> Elephant -  Tiger - Deer </b> </p>
   <input id = "textbox" type = "text" name = "q1">

      <p class = "questions">Name a US state beginning with K?</p>
   <input id = "textbox" type = "text" name = "q2">

      <p class = "questions">Who wrote the Harry Potter series? <b> Charles D. - JK Rowling - Vincent V. </b> </p>
   <input id = "textbox" type = "text" name = "q3">

      <p class = "questions">Who wrote 'The Scarlet Letter'?</p>
   <input id = "textbox" type = "text" name = "q4">

   <input id = "buttonmed" type = "button" value = "Finished!" onclick = "check();">
</form>

<div id = "medscoresheet">
      <p id = "mednumber_correct"></p>
      <p id = "medmessage"></p>
</div>      

<!-- Border for the game --> 
<form id = "divbox3hard" name = "quizhard" style="display:none;"> 
      <div class="game-button" style="width:50%"> 
         <button onclick="show('divbox3')">Easy</button>
         <button onclick="show('divbox3med')">Medium</button>
         <button onclick="show('divbox3hard')">Hard</button>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>

<!-- Hard Quiz code -->
      <p class = "questions">What chemical element is diamond made of?</p>
   <input id = "textbox" type = "text" name = "q1">

      <p class = "questions">What game features the terms love, deuce, match and volley?</p>
   <input id = "textbox" type = "text" name = "q2">

      <p class = "questions">Which planet did Superman come from?</p>
   <input id = "textbox" type = "text" name = "q3">

      <p class = "questions">How many syllables make up a haiku?</p>
   <input id = "textbox" type = "text" name = "q4">

   <input id = "buttonhard" type = "button" value = "Finished!" onclick = "check();">
</form>

   <div id = "hardscoresheet">
      <p id = "hardnumber_correct"></p>
      <p id = "hardmessage"></p>
   </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s7vc6y4L/
this is the how I have it set up right now

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at the jsFiddle and corrected it.

take a look here:
    https://jsfiddle.net/e7862c3d/

```
function show(param_div_id) {  
   var quizList = document.getElementsByClassName('quiz');

   for(var i=0; i < quizList.length; i++) {
       quizList[i].style.display = 'none';
   }
   document.getElementById(param_div_id).style.display = 'block';

}
```

You were repeating buttons inside your forms and I think its best to show/hide forms in the instance.

Comment: This is great help! I appreciate it ^^ I have another question if you can. The buttons do work right, it switches to the right DIV and that's great. When I'm on the "medium" or "hard" DIVs for some reason it's still using the question/answers from the "easy" quiz. I'm not sure what's missing here :s

Comment: Let me have a look. I only looked at the html and buttons.

Comment: Ok, your check method only has checks/answers for the simple quiz.
Simple solution would be to have checkEasy() checkMed() checkHard()

More elegant would be to store the answers in a JSON object and pass in the test that was answered. 
Or you could use a custom attribute on the input control to store the answer and check that value
<input type="text" id="q1" quiz-answer="my right answer" />

Comment: This is only the code for the easy quiz. I have a check for the medium and hard, it's close to the same code. For example this is my JS  for the medium quiz https://jsfiddle.net/uL0cxhk4/
Is my issue with the question ID's or something?

Comment: Also the "scoresheet" should be coloured relative to what quiz level it is, they're all showing up as green which is the easy quiz.

Comment: If you dont mind I have switched to using Repl.it
The code now supports data attributes for checking answers and you add a class to allow scanning of the appropriate test for scores. 
Take a look here: https://repl.it/@PaulThomas1/DimpledPhonyUser

Comment: No problem at all! It's simpler this way. The buttons seemed to have stopped working right now. https://repl.it/@HA4/TomatoAcidicAssembly
I went onto repl and put what code I have on there for each difficulty.

Comment: Ok, will clean up further when I get home : https://repl.it/@PaulThomas1/TomatoAcidicAssembly

Comment: Appreciate it! Take your time with it, it's fine, I honestly appreciate the help you're doing by taking your time. There's one issue I've realised even when I try to change the code to separate pages. If the buttons work, the check stops working and a scoresheet doesn't appear. If the scoresheet works so far it only checks the answers for the easy quiz and the buttons stop working. Not sure where the issue lies.

Comment: I've figured it all out thanks to your help! Appreciate it.

Comment: Take a look at the repl now. Cleaned it up on the script, css and html. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you start the program, it starts with the easy quiz.  When you press "medium", it swaps the code from the `divbox3` (easy) form to the code from the `divbox3medium` (medium) form.  This changes the form that you see from the easy level quiz to the medium one.  When you press the "easy" button, it swaps the code from the `divbox3` (which now contains the code for the medium quiz and no longer the code for the easy quiz) with the code from `divbox3` (which your assuming is the easy code, but it is not).

It's like this.

```
X = Easy
Y = Medium
Z = Hard
```

Press the Medium Button

```
X = Y = Medium
Y = Medium
Z = Hard
```

Press the Easy Button

```
X = X = Medium
Y = Medium
Z = Hard
```

To fix this, you could do it the hard way by making a `divbox3`, `divbox3easy`, `divbox3medium`, and `divbox3hard`.  Then you'd change the contents of `divbox3` with the contents of whatever level quiz you want, but won't overwrite the code for the easy quiz.

To fix this the easier way, you need to add a `visible` class to the visible form (not the `display: none` forms), and then change your show function to do something like this:

```
function show(param_div_id) {
    // Loop through all elements with the visible class and both remove the class and set the display to none
    // Add the visible class to param_div_id and set it's display to block
}
```